# How to get column names with where condition included?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use :

SHOW COLUMNS FROM #__tablename WHERE Field.columnname = 'any value' ;

If I use it without where condition then it retrieves all column names but I want to fetch specified column name.

Please suggest.

Comment: You should use Where condition, you can not retrieve any specific column without where. why don't you want to use `where`?

Comment: When I used where the above query does not work ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `information_schema.columns` table instead of `SHOW COLUMNS` statement. The `information_schema.columns` table is the same as `SHOW COLUMNS`, but you can work with result-set as with ordinary table. For example -

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'table name' AND table_name = 'table name';
```

Specify columns you need and WHERE filter.

Comment: But it will fetch all the cloumns but i want to fetch only those columns which meet the specified condition.

Comment: Do you want to get field names by mask?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `information_schema.columns` , and add a filter to fetch column you want, I think it works

```
    SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = 'table name' 
           AND table_name = 'table name'
           AND column_name = 'Column name'
```